# Custom Linq query Help Needed

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Programming Language : c#
Entity Framework 6.1

I have a database Table named LoanDetails which have following fields :

```
ID -> Primary Key
custID-> INT
startDate -> Datetime
endDate -> Datetime
Amount-> money
```

I want to retrieve the loan details which validity will going to end within the next thirty(30) days from today.
Kindly help me to create the LINQ query for this.
So I could show an alert to the user using the end date value of the Loan details.
Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. It's a problem solving service. Please show us what isn't working for you and we can help fix it. Don't ask us to write code for you.

Comment: Yes , its my mistake that I haven't specified what I have tried so far @MEMark ,@Enigmativity. I have written the following but no use ultimately .   using (var dc = new DCLoanManagerEntities())
            {
                var ntfcust = (from loanDetail in dc.LoanDetails
                    where ((TimeSpan a = (loanDetail.endDate- DateTime.Today).Day)<=30)
                    select loanDetail.endDate).ToList();
               
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ntfcust;
            }

Comment: So please edit your question to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cutoffDate = DateTIme.Now.AddDays(31).Date
var loans = loanDetails.Where(x=>e.EndDate < cutoffDate
```

The trick with "End of day 30 days in the future" is that this means "before first moment 31 days in the future".

So, you add 31 days, get the date (which is the point at midnight) and then end before that.

Comment: My final code to solve this ::var cutoffDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31).Date;
               
                var loans = (from loanDetail in dc.LoanDetails
                    where loanDetail.endDate < cutoffDate
                    select new{loanDetail.Customer.Name,loanDetail.Customer.phone,loanDetail.endDate}).ToList();
                if (loans.Any())
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = loans;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No item found");
                }(THANK YOU EVERY ONE FOR THIS SUPPORT)

Answer (score 0):

It will be much like below.I only showed you how your where condition should be in the query.

```
     Where((w=>w.startDate.Date >=yourStartDate.Date
            && w.endDate.Date<=yourEndDate.Date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(30,0,0,0,0)    

from ld in LoanDetails
where (ld.endDate - SqlFunctions.GetDate()) == t
select ld
```

Comment: You must be joking. Beginner mistake: IF endDate has an index, you just made sure it is not used because you do the mathematics on the side with the field. Welcome to your table scan overlord.